# How does RPC getblock get the confirmation time of the block

Tags: time

After calling the RPC method getblock. How can I get the confirmation time of this block in the genblock method?

Comment: What you mean by confirmation time?

Comment: Time of successful transaction in the block

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I get this timestamp through RPC getblock?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2466/can-i-get-this-timestamp-through-rpc-getblock)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at any block there's usually a `timestamp.set` extrinsic that contains the time that the block was proposed by the collator.

For example:

https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fws.calamari.systems%2F#/explorer/query/0x7906c21c83542b2cd3ee27d889ac2f208c97ac1d81ad5e5cb0594dea3f2505b5

The time is in unix epoc time (seconds since 1/1/1970). You can translate it manually using a [website](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php), but all programming languages will convert from that format too.